# Minimum circumscribed ellipsoid of $\mathcal H$-polytope

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, linear-programming

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the $\mathcal H$-polytope $P$ defined as follows

$$ P := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b \right\} $$

I want to compute the smallest volume ellipsoid $E$ containing $P$ (that is, $P \subseteq E$) in polynomial time.

This problem has been well studied for the case where polytope $P$ is given as the convex hull of a set of points (see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1007960531949) and [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01582144) reference, for example). However, in my case $P$ is described as an intersection of half-planes, so I cannot use the previous references unless I compute all the vertices of $P$, which has exponential complexity and, thus, is not an option.

Are there any references or research for this specific instance of the problem, where polytope $P$ is described as an intersection of half-planes?

Comment: I think the problem is $\#P$ complete and computing volume information of any kind is hard. Having said that I would recommend looking at Khachiyan's algorithm for helpful information.

Comment: Do you have any relevant reference? I already looked in Kachiyan's algorithm but once you get an ellipsoid with center in the interior of $P$ the iteration cannot proceed anymore.

Comment: According to [Stephen Boyd](https://mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf), the optimization problem is NP-hard.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks! do you think his book mentions that? so I can reference it.

Comment: @DanielTurizo I do not know and have no time to find out. However, after a couple of seconds of searching for papers, I found [Minimal Ellipsoid Circumscribing a Polytope Defined by a System of Linear Inequalities](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10898-005-3883-8), which must have some useful references.

Comment: I've searched for more than 20 papers and never found that one, thank you so much.